# Can't save edited data into database, returns NULL, how do i fix it?

Tags: c#, datagridview, entity-framework-6, edit, crud

Button2 is the edit button, now i'm supposed to edit data that show in textboxes and press edit to change the values and save the into the database and show them in gridview aswell. But for some reason it says that newEmployee.FirstName was null, what do i do?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Employee Emp = SetValues(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
        bool result = UpdateEmployee(Emp);
        ClearAll();
        Display();

    }

    public bool UpdateEmployee (Employee Emp) 
    {
        bool result = false;
        using (var entity = new NorthwindEntities())
        {               
            Employee newEmployee = entity.Employee.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == Emp.EmployeeID).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
            newEmployee.FirstName = Emp.FirstName;
            newEmployee.LastName = Emp.LastName;
            newEmployee.BirthDate = Emp.BirthDate;                
            entity.SaveChanges();
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private Employee SetValues(string FirstName, string LastName, string BirthDate)
    {
        Employee Emp = new Employee();
        Emp.FirstName = FirstName;
        Emp.LastName = LastName;
        Emp.BirthDate = BirthDate;
        return Emp;
    }
```

Comment: please do accept upvote answer if worked

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you are getting `employee` or not by doing `null` check like as below

```
Employee newEmployee = entity.Employee.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == 
  Emp.EmployeeID).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
if(newEmployee!=null)
{          
  newEmployee.FirstName = Emp.FirstName;
  newEmployee.LastName = Emp.LastName;
  newEmployee.BirthDate = Emp.BirthDate;                
  entity.SaveChanges();
  result = true;
}
```

I think you are getting error because `FirstOrDefault` returning null value , which is you are not checking

Instead of `FirstOrDefault` you must make use of `SingleOrDefault` as only one employee going to map with one ID, because Id i think in most of the cases it primary value . and you are not going to get more than one record i.e. you will receive single record only.

---

you forgot to set status of entity to modified state :`EntityState.Modified`

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{
    //set stus to modified  
    context.Entry(existingBlog).State = EntityState.Modified; 
    // Do some more work...  
    context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer would be

`newEmployee.FirstName = Emp.FirstName ?? string.Empty;`

That said I cannot tell why Emp.FirstName is null to start with. In your code the following makes no sense either

```
Employee newEmployee = entity.Employee.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == Emp.EmployeeID).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
```

since newEmployee cannot have a EmployeeID if it's new